# How to use SQL query with value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tasks (list of programming tasks)

```
TaskID  Lang          Description
---------------------------------
 1      python        test1
 2      python        test2
 3      javascript    test1
 4      python        test3
```

Assig(list of completed programming tasks by all users)

```
  Id  TaskId   UserName      Lang
  ------------------------------------     
  1   1          x1         python
  2   2          x1         python
  3   3          x2         javascript     
  4   3          x1         python
```

What I want at the end is to have the table as below:

Result

```
TaskID  Assig.UserName Lang       Completed
1       x1             python     YES
2       x2             javascript  NO
3       x1             python     YES
4       x1             python     NO
```

I have tried the below one, but I cannot capture **UserName** to be displayed:
So normally the statement would be:

```
SELECT 
  taskid, levelskill, 
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS 
    (SELECT 
      taskid 
    FROM
      assig 
    WHERE tasks.taskid = assig.taskid 
      AND tasks.lang = assig.lang) 
    THEN 'TRUE' 
    ELSE 'FALSE' 
  END AS Completed 
FROM
  tasks 
WHERE (lang = @lang) 
GROUP BY levelskill, taskid
```

Comment: where did the UserName xxx & yyy comes from ? i don't see that in your sample data at all

Comment: userName comes from Assig table. I added sample data for all tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "wanted result" isn't possible

1. task 2 in task table is "javascript" but somehow is "python" in the result.
2. there are 4 rows in the completed tasks table (assig) but only 3 task id's are referenced in that table

The combined table is this:

```
TaskID Lang    Description  assig.UserName assig.id completed
 1     python     test1          x1          1        TRUE
 2     python     test2          x1          2        TRUE
 3     javascript test1          x2          3        TRUE
 3     javascript test1          x1          4        TRUE
 4     python     test3          NULL       NULL      FALSE
```

(nb: It isn't possible to put a username beside task 4, that data does not exist.)

You can get that result from this query:

```
SELECT
      t.taskid
    , t.Lang
    , t.Description
    , a.username
    , CASE a.taskid IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS completed
    , a.id
FROM tasks t
LEFT JOIN assig a on t.taskid = a.taskid
WHERE lang = @lang
```

Note, if more than one username is assigned to a task, that query will repeat the task for each user that was working on it.